# How to Properly Import XML Data into Power BI

Tags: xml, powerbi

I'm trying to get data from an online XML file to my power bi report. I don't seem to be getting much of anything. Here's my Query:

```
let
    Source = Xml.Tables(Web.Contents("https://sharepoint.com/teams/BP/Agile/Shared%20Documents/Power%20BI%20Data/Zachs%20Uninteresting%20Things/zachs%20feed%20query1.xml")),
    Table1 = Source{1}[Table]
in
    Table1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to expand the table a couple times by clicking on the button in the query editor.

[image]